# Standard C/C++ library not installed in new installation of Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I formatted my computer and I installed VS2012 release candidate first, then VS2010 Ultimate, and lastly VS2012 Professional from [DreamSpark](http://www.dreamspark.com/). Also, after installing VS2012, I uninstalled VS2010 and VS2012 RC

I can open solutions and compile them perfectly, but when I tried to use `#include`s from the C/C++ standard library an error pop ups saying `cannot find source file stdlib.h`

I went to the VS2012 installation directory and in the include folder of VC, I only have 2 .h files (`vsgcapture` and `srv`), and nothing else.

I checked out and there was a directory called `Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0` which is from VS2010, and the .h and .lib files of C/C++ were there, so I copied/pasted everything to VS2012 and tried to compile, but some strange errors came up.

So I uninstalled everything VS-related from the control panel, I deleted all the directories from Program Files and I installed VS2012 Professional again and the VC directories are empty again. I tried Repairing it from the setup but still the same problem.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: May be you have to set environment variables

Comment: You don't have to set any environment variables to use the C standard library, and they are all set according to my project properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by installing VS2012 on another computer, copying everything inside the VC directory where all the `.lib`s and `.h`s are, and pasting them on my installation.

Now it works perfectly well.

I asked in another site and I found out that this might happen because errors in the Visual Studio installation process. If you don't have another computer to do this, you can install it on a virtual machine instead and copying them from there.

Answer (score 1):

For others with the same issue and looking for a solution other than copying files over from another machine, try the solution posted by Jeff_322089BE-DFC2-11DF-B454-B541DFD72085 [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a987f4fa-676f-4fda-ab69-2c6bcc2684c3/visual-studio-c-2012-standard-header-files-are-missing?forum=vssetup).